# How to compute/check bash comparison expression just in command line?

Tags: bash

Suppose I would like to see, how the following expression will work in `if` statement

```
[ `ps -p 4800 -o comm=` == "ssh-agent" ]
```

But I don't want to write special script for this. Can I compute and/or execute this statement just in live shell to see which boolean value it returns?

If I put this into command line, it swears.

```
$ [ `ps -p 4800 -o comm=` = "ssh-agent" ]
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected

$ [ `ps -p 4800 -o comm=` == "ssh-agent" ]
-bash: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

Comment: What does it output?

Comment: `[ .... ] && echo match || echo not_match`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `ps` returns nothing, the first string disappears and `[` only sees two arguments. Use double quotes to fix it.

```
[ "`ps -p 4800 -o comm=`" = ssh-agent ]
echo $?
```

`$?` will be 0 if the condition returns true.

BTW, you don't need the double quotes around `ssh-agent` as none of its characters is special.

Comment: But putting double quotes around both sides of a string compare may be a good habit to get into

Comment: @spuck: Understanding when single or double quotes are needed is even better :-)